I have a problem with color interference in the emulator screen

I tried to restart the pc, I deleted the AVD and created a new virtual device and the same problem remains. All of this happened after I did a reset of the pc and downloaded Android Studio again and did the latest update and installed it well. I made a project and when I tried to run it this is what happened.


Possible PC graphics driver issue, update and see if anything changes. 2) Change emulated performance of AVD and see if changing the emulated graphics performance allows the screen to be rendered correctly.

